# Can't reset HP ML110 G6 LO100 to factory defaults

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I've tried to reset the embedded LO100 using the following methods:

- Switch configuration dip switch 1
- Removing CMOS battery for more than 10 minutes

None of the methods above reset to factory default settings.

I can only access the LO100 via SSH and haven't found anything useful using the CLP to reset it.

Accessing via web UI doesn't work.

It seems that despite the server having a dedicated LO100 port, it is currently configured in "shared" mode.

How can I gain web ui access and reset to factory default settings?

**UPDATE** I managed to upgrade the firmware for the LO100 using SSH and CLP. According to [this](https://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=501887&docId=emr_na-c01567963&docLocale=en_US) it should reset the settings, but it didn't!

Comment: You mean iLO, yes ?

Comment: No this is the baby brother version "HP Lights-Out 100 (LO100)"

Comment: Little ILO100 resets it's password during FW-Update and does not load the complete defaults. Also, the BBMC does have nothing to to with CMOS or reset switches.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use ipmitool?

Like this:

```
$> ipmitool lan print
```

That should give you some IPMI output. You can boot almost any Linux from a LiveCD/Stick and just install ipmitool. I once had a HP ML110 G6 and was able to restore access to my iLO 100 through ipmitool.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Reset the Lights Out 100 Management Processor Information**

At times, one may wish to perform a reset of the Lights Out 100 (LO100) management processor found in HP Proliant 100 Series servers, without requiring a reboot of the server itself. For example, for troubleshooting problems related to Virtual KVM or any other feature.

The web based GUI **does not** provide a specific option to reset the LO100. Instead, the CLI interface (SSH) can be used to achieve this.

Connect to the LO100 using Telnet or SSH and log in using an account with Administrator User Privilege.

Then just reset the whole thing with:

```
reset map1
```

Your connection will be lost, the BMC will reset and reboot.